# Allow user to immediately cancel long-running WPF operation from button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task

In a WPF app, we have a button that the user can click to trigger a list of videos to be loaded into VLC Media Player:

```
<Button Content="{Binding RotatorButtonLabel}" Command="{Binding RotateVideosCommand}" />
```

In the view model `MainWindowVm`, we have the command to handle the button click:

```
public ICommand RotateVideosCommand => new RelayCommand(RotateVideos);

private void RotateVideos()
{
    IsRotatorActive = !IsRotatorActive;
    RotatorButtonLabel = IsRotatorActive
        ? "Stop Rotator"
        : "Rotate Videos";
    _rotatorVm = new RotatorVm
    {
        ImageVms = ImagesView.Cast<ImageVm>().ToList(),
        IsRotatorActive = IsRotatorActive
    };

    // This fires off a new thread to run the rotator, otherwise the UI freezes.
    Task.Run(() => Messenger.Default.Send(rotatorVm, "LaunchRotator"));
}
```

Note in the above command handler, we use the MVVM Light Toolkit's `Messenger` to tell the code-behind to launch the rotator.

Now in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, we have the following c'tor:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = null;
private CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Messenger.Default.Register<RotatorVm>(this, "LaunchRotator", LaunchRotator);

    // Other logic...
}
```

And then this what the above `LaunchRotator` calls:

```
private void LaunchRotator(RotatorVm rotatorVm)
{
    if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    }

    if (_cancellationTokenSource == null || _cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    }

    if (!rotatorVm.IsRotatorActive)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        return;
    }

    RotateVideos(); 
}

private void RotateVideos()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        // This is to simplify the code and simulate work.
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

If I click the "Stop Rotator" button, it can take a few seconds for the code to hit the next iteration of the `while` loop and read the `IsCancellationRequested`. How do I make it stop immediately in this scenario?

I've looked at [this example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117743/background-task-with-instant-abort-capability-in-c/191577), but it's assuming the task and the activities are all in one class; here, I have a view model and a code-behind. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to test for `IsCancellationRequested` more frequently, inside the main work?

Comment: @redcurry, when you say "main work", do you mean in the `RotateVideos` method?

Comment: Yes, specifically the work that's been replaced with `Thread.Sleep(5000)`.

Comment: That's going to launch VLC and then an event handler on a `Timer` (not shown) will switch the video. Maybe it won't take that long to launch the VLC process so when the user hits Stop, it'll be relatively quick for them to kill the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (in a practical way) and shouldn't.

If you want to stop work in another thread then the proper way is to signal the thread (like you've done) and allow the thread to stop on it's own.  Since your example workload is a `Thread.Sleep(5000)`, once it's hit, that thread cannot do anything else until the sleep has expired.  In other words, you can signal the thread properly and if it is sleeping, it will live until the sleep is complete, and then it will check the signal again.

Options:

- In this case you can pass the `Token` to the simulated workload
  using `Task.Wait(5000, token)` and using this instead of
  `Thread.Sleep(5000)`.  This way the simulated work can also be
  canceled.
- For real work; you have to use your best judgement to test the signal
  when and where it looks fair so that you're not waiting a long period
  of time to return when cancel is signaled.  Just note that making the caller wait while the
  `Thread` or `Task` properly ends itself is the best way to do
  it.  This is why `Thread.Abort` gets so much criticism and is
  discouraged.
- Another option is to fire and forget.  You can call `Cancel()` on the token source and then move on without waiting for the `Task` or `Thread` to complete.  You have to design with this in mind but it's practical.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelPuckettII. For the first option, where would the `Task.Wait(5000, token)` go in my code?

Comment: @Alex Since you're method isn't ```async``` you would replace ```Thread.Sleep(5000);``` with ```Task.Delay(5000, _cancellationToken).Wait();```

Comment: Interesting: the .Wait() has an overload that can take the `_cancellationToken`

Comment: @Alex Yes, using it in the ```Wait``` will cancel the waiting of the ```Task``` but the ```Task``` itself will continue until it's complete.  In other words, this would fall into the 'fire and forget' scenario but I would still pass the token to the ```Task``` as well so that the ```Task``` can cancel internally.  In one you're signaling the inner work of the ```Task``` to cancel and waiting for that ```Task``` to complete and in the other you're canceling the waiting altogether; in which case the ```Task``` may still be running.